# Printing first n Happy Numbers - Python

Tags: python, function, recursion

I am writing a piece of code in python that checks whether a given number is happy or not, that is taking the number and adding the sum of their squares is 1 which is a happy number or ending up with a never ending loop which defines a unhappy number. 
After that, I want to list the first n Happy Numbers. I got the checking for happy numbers down albeit sloppily, I just can't seem to figure out the listing part.

```
def adder(num):
    total=0
    if len(str(num))>1: #check if given number is double digit or not
        tens = int(str(num)[0]) # splitting the digits 
        ones = int(str(num)[1])
        total = (tens**2)+(ones**2) # summing up the squares 
        #print (total)
        return total
    else: # if the given number  is a single digit
        total = (num**2)
        #print (total)
        return total

#adder(9)

def happynumber(num, counter):
    N = adder (num) # storing the sum in a variable 


    #print ("value of n is {}".format(N)) 
    if N == 1: #checks if the sum is 1
       # print ("In just {} tries we found that {} is a happy number.".format(counter, number))
        print (number)



    else: # if the sum isn't 1, racalls the happynumber function 
        counter += 1 # keeps track of number of tries so that we don't end up in an infinite loop
        if counter < 11: # setting the limit for number of tries
            #print (counter) 
            happynumber (N, counter)
        else:
            #print ("it took us {} tries and found that the number {} is not a happy number".format(counter, number))
            return False       

counter = 0


for i in range(0,100): # listing all the happy numbers between 0 and 100
    number = i
    happynumber (number, counter)
```

Additionally, I would like it if you guys would review my writing style and give some pointers.

The problem, I am not able to list the first n numbers however way I try.

I tried using counter in the loop but to no avail.

Comment: Is it working? What's the current problem?

Comment: If it's working, you can ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Otherwise, describe the error and expected behavior clearly.

Comment: It is working, only that I am not able to list the numbers. As in, the first 10 Happy numbers.

Comment: So list it. What prevents you from doing that?

Comment: I don't understand. A number is happy if the sum of the squares of its digits is 1? Then only 1 and 10 are happy right?

Comment: After you get the sum of the squares, you need to keep squaring the digits of the resulting sum until we get 1. Example 13 is also a happy number.

Comment: So number 13 is a happy number after 2 attempts?

Comment: @Arief yes that is correct.

Comment: What if the sum of squares has 3 digits -- like is the case for 6²+9² (113) -- how will you then treat the digits?

Comment: @trincot for now i have limited the program to only two digits. If it is 3 digits then another loop to split the 3 digits would be required as I did adder function.

Comment: OK, but then the `adder` function would need a change right? Because now it only separates the last digit and takes two squares. With three digits, it should add 3 squares if I understand you correctly...

Comment: @trincot that would we correct but user Piinthesky showed a better way. Check below.

Comment: Well, that is what I was going to mention: you accepted another answer, and I wonder why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your main problem is that you want to have all your happy numbers in a list, you can easily address this by defining a list outside the recursion loop.

```
def happynumber(num, counter):
    N = adder(num)  

    if N == 1: 
        happyhappy.append(number)      #new happy number into list
    else: 
        ...continue with your code       

#-------main script-------------
happyhappy = []                        #create a list to store your happy numbers
counter = 0
for i in range(100): 
    number = i
    happynumber(number, counter)

print(happyhappy)                      #and retrieve the list
```

Having said that there is an inefficiency in your `adder()` function. It calculates only up to two digits. Even worse, it has to perform the square operation for each digit from scratch, which is very time consuming.

A better way is to pre-calculate the squares and store them in a dictionary:

```
square_dic = {str(i): i ** 2 for i in range(10)}  #create a dictionary of squares
def adder(num):                           
    s = str(num)                                  #make the number into an iterable string
    x = [square_dic[i] for i in s]                #look up the square of each digit
    return sum(x)                                 #and calculate the sum of squares
```

Thanks to list comprehensions in Python we can make it even snappier

```
square_dic = {str(i): i ** 2 for i in range(10)}
def adder(num):                                   #does exactly, what the other function did
    return sum(square_dic[i] for i in str(num))
```

Comment: Hmm interesting, how would you tune the adder function?

Comment: You're welcome. Once seen, you will easily spot similar cases in the future.

Answer (score 1):

So first off, you shouldn't have to pass your `counter` variable since it is a global variable.  I'd also probably declare it up above your methods just to make sure there are no issues.

Your next issue is you never reset your `counter` variable.  So the first time the program runs into a number that is not-happy after 10 attempts it proceeds to return false for every single number that is not happy after the first attempt.  Try adding in `counter = 0` before your `return False` line in the `if counter < 11/else` block

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with very small change to your current code. I add another input for the `happynumber` function, that is your list that you want to store the happy numbers.

I am sure this is not the most efficient way, but it shows how you can update your code.

The code :

```
def happynumber(num, counter, the_list):
    N = adder(num); 
    print ("value of n is {}".format(N));
    if counter == 0:  #THIS IS ADDED
        the_list.append(num); #THIS IS ADDED
    if N == 1: 
        print ("In just {} tries we found that {} is a happy number.".format(counter, number))
        print (num);
    else: 
        counter += 1
        if counter < 11:
            print (counter) 
            happynumber(N, counter, the_list)
        else:
            print ("it took us {} tries and found that the number {} is not a happy number".format(counter, number))
            the_list.pop(); #THIS IS ADDED
            return False       

counter = 0;

happynumber_list = []; #THIS IS ADDED
for i in range(0,100): 
    number = i
    happynumber (number, counter, happynumber_list)
```

In the first attempt, the number will be stored to the list...but if the number was found not a happy number.. then that number will be `pop` out of the list.

Here is the result :

`[1, 7, 10, 13, 19, 23, 28, 31, 32, 44, 49, 59, 68, 70, 79, 82, 86, 91, 94, 95, 97]`

Is this okay?

Comment: Hey Arief, thanks for the input. I had this idea before, but did not know how to implement it. Thank you.

Comment: Additionally, we can completely eliminate the use of the pop function by using the append function in if N==1 loop. Same result.

Comment: @user9267433 Yes, maybe that's better, but only if you use `the_list.append(number)`, the `number` is out side of the function, but it is still usable that way with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use memoization to make the use of a counter unnecessary. I would also use a generator (`yield`) so only the number of results are produced that you ask for. Then you don't have to specify a range (0, 100), but can just specify that you want the first 25 happy numbers (or whatever is needed).

Here is how that would look:

```
import itertools

def sum_digit_squares(num):
    return sum(int(i)*int(i) for i in str(num))

def happynumbers():
    memo = { 1: True }
    for i in itertools.count(): # forever (as long as getting from this iterator)
        result = None # Will become either True (happy) or False (not happy)
        visited = set()
        j = i
        while result is None:
            if j in memo: # Did we make the calculation for this one before?
                result = memo[j] 
            elif j in visited:
                result = False # endless loop detected
            else:
                visited.add(j)
                j = sum_digit_squares(j)
        for j in visited:
            memo[j] = result
        if result:
            yield i

print (list(itertools.islice(happynumbers(), 0, 25))) # Produce first 25 happy numbers
```